# How to add a delimiter after every letter/element of each column

Tags: r

I have this dataframe called `mydf`. I want to add a `/` after each element in each column and get the result.

mydf

```
rowname      val1   val2   val3
1             00    100     111
2             01    11      11
3             00    01      01
```

result

```
rowname        val1      val2    val3
    1             0/0    1/0/0    1/1/1
    2             0/1    1/1      1/1
    3             0/0    0/1      0/1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop over the 'val' columns with `lapply` and use regex lookaround pattern using `gsub` and replace by `/`.

```
mydf[-1] <- lapply(mydf[-1], function(x) 
           gsub('(?<=\\d)(?=\\d)', '/', x, perl=TRUE))
mydf
#   rowname val1  val2  val3
# 1       1  0/0 1/0/0 1/1/1
# 2       2  0/1   1/1   1/1
# 3       3  0/0   0/1   0/1
```

#### data

```
mydf <- structure(list(rowname = c("1", "2", "3"), 
val1 = c("00", "01", 
"00"), val2 = c("100", "11", "01"), val3 = c("111", "11", "01"
 )), .Names = c("rowname", "val1", "val2", "val3"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks, but why do I get it in the form of list?

Comment: @MAPK I am getting the output as a  `data.frame` updated with the dataset I used.

Answer (score 3):

Just apply the below logic on every column.

```
gsub("(.)(?=.)", "\\1/", x, perl=TRUE)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oA8zJ6/1)